# Closing tag for element '<StackPanel>' was not found Error message

Tags: c#, wpf

Anybody knows, why I get this error: "Closing tag for element 'StackPanel' was not found"

For this code:

```
<Window x:Class="BiztositasFeladat.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Stat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="249" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Type}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Date}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Amount}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Works for me. Have you tried closing and reopening the designer or rebuilding?

Answer (score 2):

restart visual studio, and then rebuild. sometimes the xaml editor gets stuck, but i don't really know why. Anyway this workaround has worked for me a few times